# How many upvotes have I received on my comments?

Tags: support, comments

A question motivated by narcissism:

Is there some way I can find out the total number of upvotes I have received on my comments?

Similarly, can I somehow get a list of all of my comments sorted by their number of votes?

Comment: Related: [(138808)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138808/158428)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can also query the live site's API for your results:

For the **current Stack Exchange API 2.2**:

- https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/1456376/comments?site=stackoverflow&sort=votes&min=5
- https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/190341/comments?site=meta.stackexchange&sort=votes&min=2

Those have been valid for the **outdated version 1.1** of the API:

- http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/546661/comments?sort=votes&min=5
- http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/158209/comments?sort=votes&min=5

Replace the number after "users" with your user id on the appropriate site.

Comment: How to use these queries?

Comment: When I try the 2.2 links, I get a hard-to-read data dump.  How can I find this in a user-friendly format?

Comment: Same question as @gerrit.

Answer (score 7):

You can find out in the data explorer; the data is updated every other month.

- [My Total Comment Score](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/s/1695/my-total-comment-score)
- [My Comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/94/my-comments) (sorted by score)
- more condensed results: [My Comment Score Distribution](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/99/my-comment-score-distribution)

and for comparison:

- [Top Rated Comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/s/1494/top-rated-comments)
- [Most Popular Commenters](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/s/975/most-popular-commenters) (by total comment upvotes)

Comment: Substitute (adapted by ACuriousMind @ Physics.SE) for the second link, which is no longer functional: http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/238582/comments-and-votes

Answer (score 5):

That's one of the more popular queries on data.stackexchange.com: [My Comment score distribution](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/99/my-comment-score-distribution). It is not as real-time as you might like though.

Comment: For my user number, it is giving a blank value in score in last row. What does that mean?

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli the last row shows comments that have no score.

Comment: Then it should show that counter in zero score. Not as blank.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Rick Sladkey's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101280/191029), I threw a quick Python webserver together so you can see a nice formatted list of a user's top comments.

Note that this is really rough (does zero error checking), but seems to work just fine. Much easier than groking JSON.

Just run it and go to `http://localhost:8000/119527`

- Replace 119527 with your user ID (unless you want to see my smart-ass comments)
- You can specify a port other than 8000 on the command line.

```python
import sys, urllib2, zlib, json
import BaseHTTPServer
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

MIN = 5

def get_json(url):
    u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    gzipped = u.read()
    data = zlib.decompress(gzipped, 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)
    return json.loads(data)

def get_username(uid):
    d = get_json('http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/{0}'.format(uid))
    return d['users'][0]['display_name']

def do_comments_html(uid, r):
    d = get_json('http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/{0}/comments?sort=votes&min={1}'.format(uid, MIN))

    r.write('<html>\r\n')
    r.write('<head><title>SO Comments</title></head>\r\n')
    r.write('<body>\r\n')

    name = get_username(uid)
    r.write('<h3>{0} has {1} comments with >= {2} votes. Here are the top {3}</h3>\r\n'.format(
        name, d['total'], MIN, min(MIN,d['pagesize'])) )
    r.write('<ul>\r\n')
    for c in d['comments']:
        url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/{0}'.format(c['comment_id'])
        r.write('<li> <a href="{0}" target="_blank">[{1}]</a>  {2}</li>\r\n'.format(url, c['score'], c['body']))
    r.write('</ul>\r\n')

    r.write('</body>\r\n</html>\r\n')


class MyHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    #Handler for the GET requests
    def do_GET(self):
        parts = self.path.split('/')
        if len(parts) != 2:
            self.send_error(404, 'Bad URL')
            return         
        try:
            uid = int(parts[1])
        except ValueError:
            self.send_error(404, 'Bad user id')
            return

        print 'UID:', uid

        mimetype = 'text/html'
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', mimetype)
        self.end_headers()

        do_comments_html(uid, self.wfile)


if sys.argv[1:]:
    port = int(sys.argv[1])
else:
    port = 8000
server_address = ('127.0.0.1', port)

httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(server_address, MyHandler)

sa = httpd.socket.getsockname()
print "Serving HTTP on", sa[0], "port", sa[1], "..."
try:
    httpd.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print 'Closing server.'
    httpd.socket.close()
```

Comment: I think you need to have at least 25,000 reputation points in order to do that.