# Which of my comments have been voted on?

Tags: support, comment-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Top comments on Stack Exchange profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88864/top-comments-on-stack-exchange-profile)
>   [How many upvotes have I received on my comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101277/how-many-upvotes-have-i-received-on-my-comments)

Is there any way to see how my comments have been voted on?  For instance, you can sort your answers by votes, but is there a similar feature for comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not real-time, but you can use this data explorer query:

[my-comment-score-distribution](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/99/my-comment-score-distribution)

That "data dumps" on that site are updated every 3 months or so (according to [this old blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/) they are monthly, but for some reason I think that information is outdated).

Comment: Wow, I've found my new favorite SE toy.  Data Explorer query is awesome!!!  Thanks!!

Comment: @Shark Haha, I was pumped when I discovered it as well.  You can certainly waste some time there =)

Answer (score 7):

For up to the minute data, use the API:

```
api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/[YOUR USER ID # HERE]/comments?sort=votes&min=5
```

(change the minimum value if necessary, this finds all qualifying Pundit comments)

See http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage for all of the other items in its bag of tricks.

Comment: ...wow.  Just wow.  +1 for making me aware of this =)