# Show vote counts on activity>comments page

Tags: feature-request, comments, information-display

It would be helpful to show vote counts on the **activity** > **comments** page, and also allow sorting by votes.

This would make it easy to see what comments other people thought were valuable or at least amusing.

Comment: Heh, you beat me to it. I would also like to be able to sort the comments by the number of up-votes.

Comment: I'd much rather have the ability to search my comments.

Comment: @animuson I'd like that too.  I still very much want an easy way to find out which of my comments were up-voted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While a nice idea, the purposeful relegating of comments to second-class-citizen status means that extra support for them isn't likely to be forthcoming.

As a consolation prize, this information is available via the Data Explorer, e.g.:
[Top ranked comments for a particular UserId](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/78483/my-top-ranked-comments).

<sub>Though the Data Explorer often doesn't have the most timely information.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed.  With this functionality I'm OK if votes are not shown on the activity page.

Comment: I've given you the bounty for this answer.  I'm holding the Accept until my site (Mathematica) is added to Data Explorer, at which time it will become an actual solution.

Comment: Mathematica.SE has been added to the Data Explorer.  Accepted as promised!