# How to see my votes count on other users' Comments

Tags: support, vote-count

Where can I see count of votes casted by me on comments posted by other users. 
I can see my question & answer votes count on my user dashboard screen. Can I also see my comments votes count.

Can anyone please point to such query/screen etc.

Note : I am not asking for voting pattern/score on comments left by me.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: No, I mean votes by me on other users comments. I have also modified the question slightly

Comment: @random: I suppose my question is different my the link you provided. I am asking my voting stats on other uesrs comments. Some what like I can see my question & answer votes count. Can I also see my comments votes count.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138808/show-vote-counts-on-activitycomments-page

Comment: This more then http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148008/how-can-i-see-comments-that-ive-upvoted

Comment: @random: based on the answer at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148008/how-can-i-see-comments-that-ive-upvoted, I cannot see my vote count on other users comments.

Comment: @random: the question is not duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100284/is-there-any-way-to-see-statistics-on-comments but of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148008/how-can-i-see-comments-that-ive-upvoted

Comment: @atur: both posts answer your question, however. *Stack Exchange sites don't have a place to show you what comments you voted on*.